# Update the state based on comparing next state with previous - hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have Tow Tabs, Activated based on swiping next/previouse View,

I have unacceptable swiping,
When I swipe to the next view I update the index to active the next Tab, And it's work well,

But If I'm in Tab 0 and swipe twice to next I got unexpected behaviour it's activate the previous Tab

What i expected if I'm in the Tab 0 and swipe twice to next I want to active just Tab 0 and so on,

So in `onScrollEndDrag` I update the tab index if current active tab is 0 update to 1 else update to 0

But when I got the previous state and compare with current state not works well or I think on it badly.

I don't know how can i expected user swiping So i don't know how can i get next State :\

I wish anybody understands what exactly i mean in this case.

Here's a [GIF](https://i.imgur.com/ahaJCF3.mp4) check it, please!

Code Snippet

```
const Tabs = [
  {
    name: 'opened',
  },
  {
    name: 'closed',
  },
];
const AppointmentScreen = () => {
  const scrollRef = useRef(null);
  const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(0);
 
 return (
    <View style={styles.appointmentsTabs}>
    {Tabs.map(({ name }, tabIndex) => (
     <TouchableOpacity
       key={tabIndex}
       onPress={() => {
        if (tabIndex === currentIndex) {
          return;
        }
        if (scrollRef.current) {
          scrollRef.current.scrollTo({
            x: tabIndex === 0 ? width : width * (tabIndex - 1),
            y: 0,
            animated: true,
          });
          setCurrentIndex(currentIndex === 1 ? 0 : 1);
        }

      }}
      delayPressIn={0}
      style={[
        styles.appointmentsBox,
        {
          backgroundColor: tabIndex === currentIndex ? '#000' : '#fff',
        },
      ]}>
      <Text
        style={[
          styles.appointmentText,
          {
            color: tabIndex === currentIndex ? '#fff' : '#000',
          },
        ]}>
        {name}
      </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  ))}
</View>
  <Animated.ScrollView
    ref={scrollRef}
    showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
    bounces={false}
    decelerationRate="fast"
    snapToInterval={width}
    onScrollEndDrag={() => {
      if (scrollRef.current) {
        setCurrentIndex((prevState) => {
          console.log('prevState: ', prevState);
          console.log('currentIndex: ', currentIndex);
          return prevState === 0 ? 1 : 0;
        });
      }
    }}
    horizontal>
    <OpenedAppointments />
    <ClosedAppointments />
  </Animated.ScrollView>
);
}
```

[Demo](https://snack.expo.io/@anastely/69b765)

Comment: To help people help you, you can create a **runnable** [mcve] using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: Hey @T.J. Crowder, it's not React snippet it's react native, so will not work on stack snippets I guess, I've already added a live demo "runnable" on snack if you want to take a look!

Comment: Ah, React Native, I missed that. Still, if the problem is state management (so not specific to React native), an MRE onsite would be good. The problem with something just being *linked* is that then all of that information is off-site. Two problems with that: People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future. A snippet is definitely not a requirement provided all the relevant information is in the question text. *(Not my downvote.)* Hope you get it sorted! :-)

Comment: You're already avoiding the mistake so many others make (nice one!) by using the callback version of `setCurrentIndex`. So hmmmm. I wonder: Do you really care whether you have the ref for updating the tab index? You might try removing that `if` and seeing if it solves the problem. Could be some tricky timing or something, and since you want to respond to the gesture and you're not actually using the ref in that update... Anyway, hope you find it!

Comment: I edit the question and add the needed code! 
I'm trying to delete `if` for ref but it's still the issue appears,  
I wish you got the point on this issue, maybe i can solve it by hooks but i couldn't find it :) if i can get the next state and compare it with previous I just activate Tab the actual view I'm on it? 
Check this [gif](https://i.imgur.com/ahaJCF3.mp4)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I solve it by getting the visible view when scrolling then set the active tab based on page number it takes a little delay when activated the tab, but it works well,
 if you wondering check it here https://snack.expo.io/@anastely/segment-tab

Comment: Congrats! :-) ..